# Ruby thread dies after redirect

Tags: ruby, multithreading

i start a thread in my controller and want to redirect the user immediately after that.

```
class Profile::GeneralController < ProfileController
    def update
       startTheThread(profile)
       #sleep(5)
       redirect_to 'selection_controller'
    end
end

class ProfileController < ApplicationController
    def startTheThread(profile = nil)
        $collector_threads[current_user.id][sector] = Thread.new {
            Thread.current['collecting_status'] = { a: 1, c: 0, c_id: -1, r: false }            
            start_threaded_collector(sector)
        }
    end
end
```

When i tell the controller to sleep for - let's say - 5 seconds, the thread finishes like it was supposed to.

The thread is dead as soon as the user changes to another page - why is that and how can i keep threads alive across controllers.

Comment: Are you running this on a multi threaded server? (not webrick)

Comment: i'm running 'thin' as webserver

Comment: You're doing something very wrong. If you have a need for some kind of asynchronous processing, you should use ActiveJob, Sidekiq or another job queue.

Comment: If you realy want to got this path, try puma. `thin` uses eventmachine. Eventmachines FAQ's states that there can be issues with other threads running around. This blog http://blog.arkency.com/2013/06/implementing-worker-threads-in-rails/ should give you some clues.

Answer (score 1):

I'm with @meagar here, this is asking for serious trouble. Presume your process will be killed after you finish making the web request, as that's something that happens under some Ruby on Rails process managers when they're pruning off excess instances.

Sharing data between controller instances should also be considered impossible unless you're persisting the data somehow: Database, session, cookies, or arguments via GET or POST.

In a typical system you'll have N Ruby processes on M machines, and the processes will be started and stopped arbitrarily, without warning, if they're not actively processing any requests. There's no way to reliably share data between these without some external IPC.

You probably want a background server process that these controllers can contact for any information they might need, or a process that can dump data into a database or a service like [Redis](http://redis.io) where it can be picked up.

The way you could architect this is by pushing a job into a Redis queue, have another process that's watching that queue for work and pops the job and processes it. This is easily done with the [`BLPOP`](http://redis.io/commands/blpop) command in Redis, where your thread will block waiting for work, then immediately continue when there's something to do.